# How portable is mktemp(1)?

Tags: shell, portability

As the title suggests — can I be reasonably sure that `mktemp` will exist on any unix-y operating system I'm likely to encounter?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84980/37512.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

POSIX does not seem to specify *mktemp(1)*.

It looks like most modern systems have it, but the available functionality and the semantics of the options vary between implementations (so particular invocations may not be portable):

- [*mktemp(1)* from OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/mktemp.1) — *mktemp(1)* originated in OpenBSD 2.1
- [*mktemp(1)* from FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp)
- [*mktemp(1)* from Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mktemp.1.html) — almost always the same as from FreeBSD
- [*mktemp(1)* from Todd C. Miller](http://www.mktemp.org/manual.html) of sudo fame
- [*mktemp(1)* from Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/mktemp-1.html#scrolltoc)
- [*mktemp(1)* from GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html#mktemp-invocation)
- [*mktemp(1)* from HP/UX](https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/mktemp.1.html) — this one seems particularly divergent from most of the others listed here

So if you want a portable solution you may need to stick to functionality and options that mean the same thing on all of your platforms of interest.

Comment: It use to be reasonably portable and defined by POSIX but it seems that some weaknesses in it were addressed by forming a new function 'mkstemp()'.  

"4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of mktemp()." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html 

The newer replacment being http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html

Comment: The `mktemp` @TafT is addressing is the C library function, whereas the `mktemp` OP asked about is the command line program.

Comment: @onlynone is one of things not often a very thin veneer around the other?

Comment: @TafT kind of. But it's not quite that thin. `mktemp.c` in gnu coreutils is 350 lines: http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/mktemp.c . And actually it doesn't look like it ever calls `mktemp(3)` instead it uses some gnulib function (not glibc) that does it's own logic and the only system call it makes is to `open`.

Comment: @TafT No - no proper implementation of `mktemp` the command line tool will use `mktemp` the deprecated C function.

Comment: HP/UX had `mktemp(1)` in 10.20 already (1996) and the revision control header in the man page had `$Header: mktemp.1,v 72.3 93/01/14 11:27:33 ssa Exp $` suggesting it had been there for much longer. So HP/UX had a mktemp command long before OpenBSD (1997).

Comment: Todd Miller did write OpenBSD's `mktemp` in the first place and later made it a portable utility, the one used on Linux distributions until GNU wrote their own compatible one.

Comment: Actually, [HP/UX 7.0 (1989) already had a mktemp utility](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_hp9000hpux0ReferenceVol1Section1Sep89_33991967/09000-90013_HP-UX_7.0_Reference_Vol_1_Section_1_Sep89_djvu.txt) and it looks like 6.x didn't. Ultrix 4.0 (1990) also had a mktemp with the same API.

Answer (score 7):

A `mktemp` *function* (AKA `mktemp(3)`) first appeared in Unix V7 so it's likely to be everywhere.  However, a `mktemp` *command* (aka `mktemp(1)`) first appeared, I believe, on OpenBSD 2.1, so if you have to deal with truly antediluvian Unix systems you *might* have to worry -- unless you can distribute the very portable [mktemp.org](http://www.mktemp.org/readme.html) version (to fix the potential lack of this utility on some customer's antediluvian system).  How likely you are to encounter antediluvian system is nigh impossible for us to guess, of course -- e.g., in `HP-UX`, `mktemp(1)` has been around for at least 8 years (even most enterprises probably have updated their Unix OS's within that time frame), in Xenix I believe it appeared in 3.0 (in 1992), etc, etc.

Comment: So the short summary is: yes, you can reasonably rely on mktemp being around

Answer (score 5):

FYI, mktemp appears to NOT be included with Solaris 9 (released 2002/2003) - just ran across this today:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS dcmnapp02 5.9 Generic_122300-47 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440
$ mktemp
bash: mktemp: command not found
$ man mktemp
bash-2.05$ man mktemp
Reformatting page.  Please Wait... done

Standard C Library Functions                           mktemp(3C)

NAME
     mktemp - make a unique file name

SYNOPSIS
     #include 

     char *mktemp(char *template);
```

Comment: Yes, Solaris 10 was the first Solaris release to include the mktemp(1) command in the OS.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris 9 it's in package SMCmktemp, see http://sunfreeware.com/indexsparc9.html:

> uname -s
>   SunOS
>   uname -r
>   5.9
>   /usr/sbin/pkgchk -l -p /usr/local/bin/mktemp
>   Pathname: /usr/local/bin/mktemp
>   Type: regular file
>   Expected mode: 0555
>   Expected owner: bin
>   Expected group: bin
>   Expected file size (bytes): 8884
>   Expected sum(1) of contents: 6493
>   Expected last modification: Nov 05 08:48:17 2002
>   Referenced by the following packages:
>           SMCmktemp
>   Current status: installed

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Yes, the service has moved to https://unixpackages.com and has become a paid service.