# How to create a temporary file with portable shell in a secure way?

Tags: shell, posix, portability, temporary-files, secure-coding

I want to create a temporary file in POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`).

I found out that `mktemp(1)` doens't exist on my AIX box, and according to [How portable is mktemp(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792675/how-portable-is-mktemp1), it isn't that portable and/or secure anyway.

So, what should I use instead ?

Comment: Well, it isn't a sysadmin question, but a _coding_ one (be it in unix shell).

Comment: What kind of security do you need on this temporary file?  That affects what you can use.

Comment: @evilotto: well _secure_ mostly means _not guessable_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not use `/dev/random`?

It could be neater with perl but od and awk will do, something like:

```
tempfile=XXX-$(od -N4 -tu /dev/random | awk 'NR==1 {print $2} {}')
```

Comment: That's _exactly_ what i was looking for (secure & POSIX). Didn't think about `/dev/random`, but it feels so obvious once said :)

Comment: For almost all purposes /dev/urandom is preferable.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324210/197479.  Using hex is shorter.  Tested this on AIX6.1: tempfile=XXX-$(od  -N4 -tx /dev/urandom | awk 'NR==1 {print $2} {}')

Comment: The pipe to `awk` can be avoided altogether as `-An` is portable: `tempfile=$(od -An -N4 -tx /dev/urandom); tempfile=XXX-${tempfile## }`

Comment: Also, to convert an arbitrary number of bytes one can do: `length=7; tempfile=XXX-$(od -An -N${LENGTH} -tx1 /dev/urandom | tr -d ' ')`

Comment: I don't think /dev/random is specified by POSIX.

Comment: You can also use regular expressions to retrieve just the hexa digits:
`[[ $rnd =~ ([[:xdigit:]]+) ]] && rnd=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`

Comment: `tempfile=$(od -An -N4 -tx /dev/urandom | tr -C -d '[:xdigit:]')` remove all except hex digits.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't exactly define "secure", but one element of it is probably to clean up after yourself.

```
trap "rm -f \"$tmpfile\"" 0 1 2 3 15
```

You can probably `man 3 signal` to see if there are other signals that should cause your temp file to be erased.  Signal zero means "on a clean exit".

Answer (score 1):

Got here from google for portable mktemp. My needs are less secure than OP's, so I ended up just using the script's PID:

```
tempx=/tmp/mytemp.$$
```