# shell: how to create a unique temporary file path cross-platform/portable?

Tags: shell, datetime, cross-platform, posix, temporary-files

How to create a unique file path in a shell cross-platform? I have looked around on most of the answers and it seems that no cross-platform/portable solution is simple enough. `mktemp` seems to be the most solid alternative on platforms where mktemp is availible. When it is not availible `/dev/random` on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224921/how-to-create-a-temporary-file-with-portable-shell-in-a-secure-way) can also be an alternative. If some kind of time traceability is wanted then what would be the next alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple that is included in the posix standard is to use mktemp. If that is not availible date is the next second option. %s parameter of date may also not be availible on all legacy platforms.

```
date "+%s-%N"
```

%s seconds since epoch and %N nano seconds to be dead sure of the uniqueness.

With more context:

```
TEMPDIR=/tmp/`date "+%s-%N"`
```