# How can heredocs be used with xargs?

Tags: find, posix, xargs, heredoc, ed

## Background

I'm looking to strip any `# TODO` comments from some python source code files output by `git archive` before sending it off. I'm looking to do so from a script that will be run from a variety of *nix OSes, so it should be as POSIX-compliant as possible.

I'm aware that `find -print0` and `xargs -0` aren't in the base spec, but they appear to be common enough that I'm fine with using them (unless a better alternative exists). I'm using `ed` due to `sed -i` not being in the base spec for in-place editing. Assume the command below is being run from the directory of an already un-tar'd git archive.

I'd be happy with an overall alternative solution for stripping the `# TODO` comments out, but to satisfy my curiosity I'd also like an answer to the particular problem I'm facing with the command I've come up with.

## Existing Code

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} ed -s {} << 'EOF'
,g/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO/d
,s/[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO//
w
EOF
```

## Expected Result

All files ending in ".py" are stripped of full lines that only contain TODO comments, or end-of-line comments starting with TODO.

## Actual Result

(stdout)

```
,g/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO/d
,s/[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO//
w
: No such file or directory
```

## Current Theory

I believe that the `<< 'EOF'` heredoc is being applied to `xargs` instead of `ed`, and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the `<< 'EOF'` heredoc direction would take some `sh -c` trickery that ended up causing even more problems, so I tried re-approaching the problem without requiring heredocs at all.

I ended up landing on:

```sh
inline() {
    # Ensure a file was provided
    in="${1?No input file specified}"
    # Create a temp file location
    tmp="$(mktemp /tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX)"
    # Preserve the original file's permissions
    cp -p "$in" "$tmp"
    # Make $@ be the original command
    shift
    # Send original file contents to stdin, output to temp file
    "$@" < "$in" > "$tmp"
    # Move modified temp file to original location, with permissions and all
    mv -f "$tmp" "$in"
}

find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -ilE '#[ \t]*TODO' {} \+ | while read file; do
    inline "$file" sed -e '/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO/ d' -e 's/[ \t]*#[ \t]*TODO//'
done
```

`mktemp` isn't technically in the base spec, but [appears to be fairly portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792675/how-portable-is-mktemp1) so I'm fine including it. `ed` was also causing me some problems, so I went back to `sed` with a custom function to replicate the unavailable `-i` flag for in-place operations.

Comment: Damn, I have started using heredocs all over the place and rely so much on xargs :( I guess I can create a temporary file from heredoc and call it in an xargs pipe

Comment: Just one more note about here docs: tabs get screwed up, don't put tabs in here docs.