# How to use xargs with ed?

Tags: pipe, xargs, heredoc, ed, herestring

I want to batch replace strings recursively inside a folder, and I have settled with using Perl.  I would like to see if there is a solution which requires less dependency and work across platforms.

For listing files, I can use anything from `ls` to `find` to `ag`, `rg`.  Lemme demonstrate my problem with `ls`.

`ls | xargs -I '{}' ed -s {} <<< $'='`

I will get this:

`Is a directory
newline appended
=: No such file or directory`

As the pipe is used for passing filenames to `xargs`, and streams (here-string) seems not working ([How can heredocs be used with xargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994643/how-can-heredocs-be-used-with-xargs)).  I wonder if it is possible to use `xargs` with `ed`.

My concern is cross platform and in fact that command will be put inside `package.json` for `npm run global_replace`.  We are wondering if there are solutions other than introducing `gulp-replace` and `gulp` just for this task.

Comment: What command are you trying to run in ed? `$'='` is reduced to just `=` by the shell (ANSI-C quoting) and will print the line number of the current line, which is the last one.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sorry for the bad example.  Another one may be `$'2,5d\nw'` which is to delete those lines and save.  My point was to demonstrate that herestring doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, using herestring is not completely impossible:

`find ... | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'ed -s "$1" <<< '"$',s/foo/bar/g\nw'" -- {}`

And in `package.json`, I have to escape each `"`, so now we can run `npm run replace`.  The exit code will be status 1 and it does not look good although it works.

Many thanks to @Benjamin.W for his help in the comments!

Comment: You can move parts of the argument to `sh -c` to be double quoted and the rest single quoted, like this: `sh -c 'ed -s "$1" <<< '"$',s/foo/bar/g\nw'"`. Make sure to quote `$1`, or the whole benefit of `-print0` and `xargs -0` is lost again.

Comment: "newline appended" indicates that the file didn't have a newline on the last line and ed added one. Some editors create files like that, but they shouldn't, according to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
find . -name "*" | xargs sed -i 's/regex/replacestring/g'
```

Comment: Thanks! I once thought that `sed` would be platform-independent enough.  However `sed` was different for "natural" Linux setup and MacOS, and that even with `sed -i '' '...'` there are illegal bytes which needs `LC_ALL=C` which converts line endings.  Hope that `ed` behaves better.