# Bash math - Dividing a bunch of rows using for statement

Tags: bash, for-loop

Example file:

```
    25      Firstname1 Lastname1     domain1.com    planname    @1.00 USD       Monthly Active  04/24/2016      Edit
    1068    Firstname2 Lastname2     domain2.com    planname   @7.95 USD       Annually Active  05/09/2016      Edit
    3888    Firstname3 Lastname3     domain3.com    planname    @19.95 USD      Biennially Active  05/04/2016      Edit
```

I am extracting just the price and billing cycle and am converting the billing cycles into numerical value this way I can divide the price by the billing cycle to get a cost per month.

When using the for statement, its adding line breaks which is breaking the math.

Code:

```
    for i in `cat asd | cut -d "@" -f 2 | awk '{print $1, $3}' | sed 's/Monthly/\/ 1/g' | sed 's/Annually/\/ 12/g' | sed 's/Biennially/\/ 24/g' |grep -Ev 0.00` ; do echo $i | bc -l' ; done
```

I would prefer to be able to get 1 answer meaning all the rows get divided up then added together to get one final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: (If you are totally set on a single line)

```
cat asd | cut -d "@" -f 2 | awk '{print $1, $3}' | sed 's/Monthly/\/ 1/g' | sed 's/Annually/\/ 12/g' | sed 's/Biennially/\/ 24/g' | grep -Ev 0.00 | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" | bc -l; done | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc -l
```

But this would be way more clear:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat asd | cut -d "@" -f 2 | awk '{print $1, $3}' | sed 's/Monthly/\/ 1/g' | sed 's/Annually/\/ 12/g' | sed 's/Biennially/\/ 24/g' | grep -Ev 0.00 > $tmp

tmp2=$(mktemp)
cat $tmp | while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line" | bc -l >> $tmp2
done

# Actual output
cat $tmp2 | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc -l
rm $tmp $tmp2
```

Comment: Several examples of useless use of `cat`.  There can be portability issues with `mktemp`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792675/how-portable-is-mktemp1

Answer (score 1):

All those calls to `cat`, `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `grep` and `bc` - what a waste.

This is a mis-named post, because you are not using Bash to do any calculations.  The reason is that `bash`, unlike korn shell (`ksh`), does not support floating point.  So you fall back to utilities like `bc`.  Hold on though, `awk` supports floating point as well.

`awk` is a programming language in its own right.  This just uses one instance of `awk`.  I have embedded it inside a bash script because you are probably doing other stuff, but with a little adjustment it could be stand-alone with `#!/bin/awk` at the top:

```
infile='asd'

# -f - means "read the program from stdin"
# << '_END_' is a here document.  Redirect stdin from here to the label _END_
awk -f - "$infile" << '_END_'
BEGIN {
# an associative array for the billing cycles
cycles["Monthly"]    = 1
cycles["Annually"]   = 12
cycles["Biennially"] = 24
}

{
sub(/@/,"",$6)          # Remove the @ from the amount
total += $6/cycles[$8]  # divide amount by the billing cycle, add to total
}
END { print total }
_END_
```

Don't you think this is simpler to understand and maintain?  It's also more efficient.  This awk script is probably a good exercise for an *awk 101* training course.