# git ls-files for different branch

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I want to find all markdown files in the base directory of a specified branch. `git ls-files` was suggested to me, but the documentation doesn't mention specifying a branch. I want to be able to do this without checking out that branch. Can this be done?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree

Comment: I don't see a way to filter based on file extension.  `git ls-files *.md' showed me all markdown files in the current branch, and `git ls-tree --name-only origin/master` shows me all the files in `origin/master`. Will I have to filter myself, or is there a flag I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git ls-files` examines files in the *index* or the *work-tree* (or both).  Since the current index and work-tree contents generally reflect the current commit as extracted from the tip of the current branch, it won't work this way.  But there is a workaround.

As [VonC notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55546074/1256452), `git ls-tree` examines a *tree* object, such as that stored in a commit.  However, `git ls-tree` does not accept pathspec arguments such as `**/*.md`.

The workaround is to read the commit of interest into a *temporary* index.  To do that cleanly, use `mktemp` to make a temporary file, then remove the temporary file and use `git read-tree` to re-create the file as valid a temporary index containing the image of the commit you wish to inspect, which you can then inspect with `git ls-files`.  For example:

```
$ cd git
$ sh -c 'export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp); rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE; git read-tree e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290; git ls-files -- "*.h" "**/*.h"; rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE'
cache.h
$ sh -c 'export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp); rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE; git read-tree origin/master; git ls-files -- "*.md"; rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE'
.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
README.md
contrib/vscode/README.md
```

(Note: the `sh -c 'export ...; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'` is all required, although if you're already using a POSIX-compatible shell you can replace `sh -c` with parentheses for a subshell.  We need the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to stay set for just those commands.  If your `mktemp` has `-u`, consider using that instead of the first `rm`.  See also [How portable is mktemp(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2792675/1256452))

Comment: I don't understand the point of creating a temporary file and immediately removing it. Then you remove `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` again after `git read-tree`, which should give you an error, because you already removed that temporary file in the first invocation of `rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE`. Could you explain this a little further?

Comment: @EarthIsHome: Try it without removing it and observe the effect.  (Seriously, try it. Is this a bug in Git? I would argue that it could be considered one.) Note that if your `mktemp` has `-u` you can use this flag instead of a separate initial `rm`.  Also, consider as an exercise answering the question: "what file(s) does git read-tree create".

Comment: I did try it. It changed my index to what I `git read-tree` without changing my HEAD or files in my working tree. I `reset --hard` back to the branch that my HEAD was pointed at.

Comment: I guess, I don't understand how git is using the temporary file created by `mktemp`.

Comment: You must have left out the `export` or not run this as a single separate sub-shell command. The environment variable `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` names a file that Git should use as a temporary index, but this file must either *not exist* (in which case Git creates a valid index), or else must *contain a valid index* (in which case Git uses that as the starting point for operations like read-tree). An empty (zero-byte) file is not a valid index as it is missing its checksum.

Comment: Ah, not understanding `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is the source of my misunderstanding. This makes sense now! Thank you. And yes, you were right, I wasn't in a subshell; I was just playing around in my main shell.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree), you might need to filter the output yourself, to grep what you need.

As mentioned [in this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/ls-tree-and-wildcards-td7553581.html) back in 2012:

> There are two uses of "pattern" there, and the former is probably OK but
>   the latter is indeed misleading.
>
> Back when we wrote this command, there were two distinct "pathspec" families, and `ls-tree` belong to the one with "`diff`" family that did *not* take anything but "leading path pattern" (the other one from "`ls-files`" and "`grep`" family allowed wildcards).  Giving a wildcard to the command in the "`ls-tree`/`diff`" family was never supported.
>
> If you change `ls-tree` to use its paths arguments as pathspec, you will
>   break backward compatibility.